# mongo db findOneAndUpdate not returning document but updating it

Tags: mongodb

findOneAndUpdate updates the document but returns with the error

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
    { verificationHash: req.query.hash },
    { $unset: {verificationHash: ''}}).then((err, user) => {//some code}
);
```

in this case my document is updated but user in callback is always undefined and content of error looks like

```
{
   lastErrorObject: {n:1, updatedExisting: true},
   value: document,
   ok: 1
}
```

Am i missing something here or is this how the object in the callback is returned?

Comment: For mongoose (and some answers that refer to mongo shell): [db.collection.findOneAndUpdate () is not returning the "updated" document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64941311/db-collection-findoneandupdate-is-not-returning-the-updated-document?noredirect=1)

Answer (score 0):

When executing `.findOneAndUpdate` in mongoDB then use `{returnNewDocument: true}` or if using mongoose you can use `{new : true}`.

Set the `returnNewDocument` as true and you will get updated document.

```
collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  { verificationHash: req.query.hash }, // query
  { $unset: {verificationHash: ''}},  // update condition
  { returnNewDocument: true }, // returns updated document
  function (err, documents) {
    res.send({ error: err, affected: documents });
    db.close();
  }
)
```

Comment: so when i pass the callback function i get the 2nd argument same as i was getting as 1st argument when using promise.then
{
   lastErrorObject: {n:1, updatedExisting: true},
   value: document,
   ok: 1
}

Comment: I am having the same issue. Have you tried to look inside the value objcet?
documents.value contains the information updated in the Db.