# db.collection.findOneAndUpdate () is not returning the "updated" document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

following the official [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/),

```js
db.students2.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id : 1 },
   [ { $set: { "total" : { $sum: "$grades.grade" } } } ],  // The $set stage is an alias for ``$addFields`` stage
   { returnNewDocument: true }
)
```

### My implementation,

```js
const usersCollection = db().collection("users"); // db() is exposed via a module

usersCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id : new ObjectID (this.data._id)},
   { $set: { 
           total : this.data.updatedTotal
        }
    } ,
   { returnNewDocument: true }
)
```

#### despite the `{ returnNewDocument: true }` option, it still returns the old document

### But, when I query the collection again,

```js
usersCollection.findOne({_id: new ObjectID()}); // returns the updated document
```

it returns the updated document. Which means that the `db.collection.findOneAndUpdate()` worked.

#### the problem is, it's not returning the updated document, despite the `{ returnNewDocument: true }`  option .

### Why is that ?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/32811548/5990249

Comment: you have to add one more argument `{new:true}` for monoose to understand you need updated document

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return it you need to add

```
{returnOriginal: false}
```

Always check the [Node JS MongoDB API](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Collection.html#findOneAndUpdate)

Answer (score 1):

For mongoose to return the new document, you need to add { new: true } to the query.

I would give this as shot:

```
usersCollection.findOneAndUpdate(
   { _id : new ObjectID (this.data._id) },
   { $set: { total : this.data.updatedTotal } },
   { new: true }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Node mongodb driver: `returnOriginal`  was Deprecated, use `returnDocument` with "before" or "after" instead.

```
{returnDocument: 'after'}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it.

### Since I am using the native mongodb driver,

we'll want to use `{returnOriginal: false}` instead of `{new: true}`.